# Specify file extension on Report Library

Tags: document-library, library

I created a Report Library (as below). Now, I'm trying to create a report on it.

[image]

[image]

But, default extension is `xlsx` and can't change it.

[image]

How can it be changed acceptance extension to `docx` for example?